# Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update

I have this error for `Oper = 'UPD'` line and I don't know how to fix it.

**Error** :

> ````
> TRIGGER INSSECR_LOG_EMP Line/Col: 21/13 PLS-00103: Encountered the
> symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
>
>    := . ( @ % ; ```
> ````

Here is the **trigger** :

```sql
create or replace trigger insSECR_LOG_emp
  after insert or delete or update on emp
declare 
    v_day  VARCHAR2(20);
    v_time VARCHAR2(20);
    id_us  VARCHAR2(20);
begin
    select to_char(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY ') into v_day from dual;
    select to_char(sysdate, ' HH24:MI:SS') into v_time from dual;
    SELECT USER  into id_us FROM DUAL;
  if inserting then
    update SECR_LOG set
     Oper = 'INS';
  elsif deleting then
    update SECR_LOG set
     Oper = 'DEL';
  elsif updating then
    update SECR_LOG set
     Oper = 'UPD';
  end if;
  update SECR_LOG set
      table_ = 'emp';
      Uname = id_us ;
      Sdate = v_day;
      Stime = v_time;
end;
```

Please correct me

Answer (score 1):

The last `UPDATE` is wrong.

**No**:

```
update SECR_LOG set
  table_ = 'emp';
  Uname = id_us ;
  Sdate = v_day;
  Stime = v_time;
```

**Yes**:

```
UPDATE SECR_LOG
  SET table_ = 'emp',
      Uname = id_us,
      Sdate = v_day,
      Stime = v_time;
```

---

Note that none of `UPDATE` statements has a `WHERE` clause, which means that all of them will be updating the **whole table**.